# Downgrade of .netsdk

Tags: .net

yesterday I have updated my .net to test Maui, not a wise choice, currently I hold `6.0.100-preview.5.21302.13` some stuff works, some doesn't. What is worst is that I can't connect to local host. So if I run my proxy `iisexpress-proxy` I  can't connect to my address - Safari can't connect to the server. How do I downgrade back to .net 5?

Comment: have you tried using a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file in the solution/project root, to pin the .NET SDK version to v5? use `dotnet --info` to get the exact available runtime names to use, but it is *probably* `"5.0.301"` (note: you'll probably need to restart any IDEs etc after changing the SDK version)

Comment: Another good reason to use version control on all projects.

Comment: Hello, I have done that. But still can't connect on proxy :)